# Subscribe to Salesforce Change Data Capture using Apache Camel CometD component

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce, cometd

I am trying to write a Java DSL route to subscribe to Salesforce Change Data Capture channel. However, my limitation is to not use username & password rather prefer OAuth for the authentication.

I am not able to find a way to pass OAuth credentials (i.e access-key/refresh token) as part of the initializing camel-cometd component. Can someone please guide me through the way to provide details to camel component?

Answer (score 0):

The camel-cometd component is very old, and its a shame that Salesforce uses such an old technology in their Java client.

And as such this old camel-cometd component does not support what you ask for.

It would be better to have built in support for change data capture in camel-salesforce. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket. But salesforce is not "fun" to work with, and so maybe it takes a while for anyone to implement this freely. However commercial companies like Red Hat support Apache Camel, and you can if you are a Red Hat customer ask them for help and prioritize to get camel-salesforce improved.